# Create files if they don't already exist

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have many text files enumerated. I want to add missing text files and fill them with 0; e.g.,:

```
   -directory
     -1.txt
     -2.txt
     -6.txt
```

I want to add 3.txt, 4.txt, and 5.txt to the directory. Each text file contains one character, 0. Here's an example:

> ```
>    -directory
>      -1.txt
>      -2.txt
>      -3.txt
>      -4.txt
>      -5.txt
>      -6.txt
> ```

Can this be done with a simple command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change 6 with whatever number you want.

```
touch {1..6}.txt
```

touchs the existing files and create an empty one for missing ones.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -size 0 -exec tee <<<"0" {} +
```

Adds number `0` to all empty files. remember that if your already existing files are empty it will add zero to all of them too.

---

A not efficient way:

```
for i in {1..100}.txt; do if [ ! -f "$i" ]; then echo 0 > "$i"; fi; done;
```

Looks for `.txt` files between `1` to `100` one by one and creates them if they're not there. Created files have one text character, "0"; existing files are not modified.